# Pgfplot logaxis customization

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to reproduce the following picture:

[image]

but currently I am able to:

[image]

There are a lot of issues:

- log scales are not logarithmic, i.e. `256, 512, 1020, 2050`. I would like to have `256, 512, 1024, 2048`
- y and x axis are nothing like the original
- x grid is redundant, see original picture

  ```
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \begin{loglogaxis}[
              /pgf/number format/.cd,
                  use comma,
                  1000 sep={},
              xmode=log,
              log basis x=2,
              log basis y=2,
              log ticks with fixed point,
              xlabel={Block size},
              ylabel={Decoding latency, ns/op},
              grid=major,
              legend entries={Critical, JNI, FOR, VInt},
              legend pos=south east,
              xmin=128,xmax=16384,
              ymin=60,ymax=30000,
              ytick={120, 240, 480, 960, 1920, 3840, 7680, 15360},
              xtick=data
          ]
          \addplot[red,very thick,mark=square*] coordinates {     
              (128, 82.638)
              (256, 139.914) 
              (512, 225.505)
              (1024, 396.605) 
              (2048, 743.370) 
              (4096, 1436.633)
              (8192, 2827.855)
              (16384, 5654.820)
          };    
          \addplot[green,very thick,mark=triangle*] coordinates {     
              (128, 200.452)
              (256, 261.881) 
              (512, 341.506)
              (1024, 518.709) 
              (2048, 868.560) 
              (4096, 1557.861)
              (8192, 2953.913)
              (16384, 5779.984)
          };    
          \addplot[blue,very thick,mark=diamond*] coordinates {     
              (128, 194.441)
              (256, 346.855) 
              (512, 592.312)
              (1024, 1100.371) 
              (2048, 2089.506) 
              (4096, 4204.929)
              (8192, 7758.365)
              (16384, 14938.887)
          }; 
          \addplot[orange,very thick,mark=*] coordinates{     
              (128, 330.123)
              (256, 583.440) 
              (512, 1046.636)
              (1024, 2149.478) 
              (2048, 4058.115) 
              (4096, 8023.846)
              (8192, 14458.539)
              (16384, 25235.819)
          }; 
      \end{loglogaxis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
  ```

Comment: You can try with `xtick={256,512,1024,2048}` or `xtick=data` , I don't understand when you say "y and x axis are not the same" and "x grid is redundant"

Comment: @juanuni `xtick={256,512,1024,2048}` did not help, the values still rounded. I mean they are nothing like the original

Comment: Try with `xtick=data` if you data contain that numbers ...

Comment: @juanuni `xtick=data` did not help

Comment: Could you provide the code for your figure? Regarding your second comment, use the options `xmin`, `ymin`, `xmax`, `ymax` in the `axis` environment. And as juanuni, I understand what you mean by "x grid is redundant".

Comment: @anderstood Sorry, I forgot to add source code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little tedious but gets pretty close with lots of tweaks (shadow is also possible but please don't do it. It's just an Excel trick that, in my opinion doesn't help for anything visually):

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{sansmath}
\sansmath 

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
a,b,c,d,e
128,  82.638  ,200.452 ,194.441  ,330.123  
256,  139.914 ,261.881 ,346.855  ,583.440  
512,  225.505 ,341.506 ,592.312  ,1046.636 
1024, 396.605 ,518.709 ,1100.371 ,2149.478 
2048, 743.370 ,868.560 ,2089.506 ,4058.115 
4096, 1436.633,1557.861,4204.929 ,8023.846 
8192, 2827.855,2953.913,7758.365 ,14458.539
16384,5654.820,5779.984,14938.887,25235.819
}\mytable

\begin{document}\sffamily
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,use comma,1000 sep={},}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[
            log basis x=2,log basis y=2,
            label style={font=\tiny},
            xlabel={Block size},ylabel={Decoding latency, ns/op},
            legend entries={Critical, JNI, FOR, VInt},
            xmin=128,xmax=16384,
            ymin=60,ymax=30720,
            separate axis lines,
            axis x line*=bottom,
            axis y line*=left,
            axis line style={draw=gray!50},
            ytick={60,120,240,480,960,1920,3840,7680,15360,30720},
            yticklabel={\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}\pgfmathparse{60*(2^(\ticknum))}%
                        \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=0]\pgfmathresult%
                        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
                        },
            xticklabel={\pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu}\pgfmathparse{2^(8+\ticknum)}%
                        \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed]\pgfmathresult%
                        \pgfkeys{/pgf/fpu=false}%
                        },
            x tick label as interval,
            ymajorgrids,
            tick align=outside,
            legend style={draw=none,fill=none,
                          at={(axis description cs:1.1,0.5)}, 
                          anchor=west,nodes={font=\tiny}},
            tick label style={font=\tiny}
        ]
        \addplot[red,very thick,mark=square*]     table[x=a,y=b] {\mytable};    
        \addplot[green,very thick,mark=triangle*] table[x=a,y=c] {\mytable};    
        \addplot[blue,very thick,mark=diamond*]   table[x=a,y=d] {\mytable}; 
        \addplot[orange,very thick,mark=*]        table[x=a,y=e] {\mytable}; 
    \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! But there is one issue with x axis. Currently xticklabel located to the left of a tick. While in the original picture it is located directly under the point. It looks little bit confusing

Comment: @Ivan Ah missed that. You can change the xtick from data to 192,... etc. just like the y axis stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking for?

[image]

Sorry I'm in a rush so no time to comment much, but here is the code. I guess you can fiddle to fit your needs.

Note that your points do not seem to correspond to the original plot (for example, where is the point $(128, 82.638)$ in the red original curve ?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{loglogaxis}[title=Random Dataset,height=10cm,width=12cm,
        scaled ticks=false,
        log ticks with fixed point,
        enlargelimits={upper=0.3},
        ymin=64,ymax=15360,xmin=64,xmax=16384,
        log basis y =2,
        xtickten={0,...,16},
        log basis x =2,
        ytick={60,120, 240, 480, 960, 1920, 3840, 7680, 15360},
        yticklabels={60,120, 240, 480, 960, 1920, 3840, 7680, 15360},
        xticklabels={1,2,4,8,16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048,4096,8192,16384},
        xlabel={Block size},
        ylabel={Decoding latency, ns/op},
        ymajorgrids,
        legend entries={Critical, JNI, FOR, VInt},
        legend pos=south east,
        xmin=128,xmax=16384,
        ymin=60,ymax=16384,
        ytick={120, 240, 480, 960, 1920, 3840, 7680, 15360},
    ]

        \addplot[red,very thick,mark=square*] coordinates {     
            (128, 82.638)
            (256, 139.914) 
            (512, 225.505)
            (1024, 396.605) 
            (2048, 743.370) 
            (4096, 1436.633)
            (8192, 2827.855)
            (16384, 5654.820)
        };    
        \addplot[green,very thick,mark=triangle*] coordinates {     
            (128, 200.452)
            (256, 261.881) 
            (512, 341.506)
            (1024, 518.709) 
            (2048, 868.560) 
            (4096, 1557.861)
            (8192, 2953.913)
            (16384, 5779.984)
        };    
        \addplot[blue,very thick,mark=diamond*] coordinates {     
            (128, 194.441)
            (256, 346.855) 
            (512, 592.312)
            (1024, 1100.371) 
            (2048, 2089.506) 
            (4096, 4204.929)
            (8192, 7758.365)
            (16384, 14938.887)
        }; 
        \addplot[orange,very thick,mark=*] coordinates{     
            (128, 330.123)
            (256, 583.440) 
            (512, 1046.636)
            (1024, 2149.478) 
            (2048, 4058.115) 
            (4096, 8023.846)
            (8192, 14458.539)
            (16384, 25235.819)
        }; 

\end{loglogaxis}  
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need `pgfplots` package. Note the use of `xtick=\empty`, `extra x ticks`, `extra x tick labels`, `extra y ticks` and `extra y tick labels`

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

%\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{loglogaxis}[xtick=\empty,extra x ticks={256, 512, 1024, 2048,4096,8192,16384},extra x tick labels={256, 512, 1024, 2048,4096,8192,16384},ytick=\empty,extra y ticks={60,120,240,480,960,1920,3840,7680,15360,30720},extra y tick labels={60,120,240,480,960,1920,3840,7680,15360,30720},
        /pgf/number format/.cd,
            use comma,
            1000 sep={},
        xmode=log,
        log basis x=2,
        log basis y=2,
        log ticks with fixed point,
        xlabel={Block size},
        ylabel={Decoding latency, ns/op},
        grid=major,
        legend entries={Critical, JNI, FOR, VInt},
        legend pos=south east,
        xmin=128,xmax=16400,
        ymin=60,ymax=31000,
        ]
    \addplot[red,very thick,mark=square*] coordinates {     
        (128, 82.638)
        (256, 139.914) 
        (512, 225.505)
        (1024, 396.605) 
        (2048, 743.370) 
        (4096, 1436.633)
        (8192, 2827.855)
        (16384, 5654.820)
    };    
    \addplot[green,very thick,mark=triangle*] coordinates {     
        (128, 200.452)
        (256, 261.881) 
        (512, 341.506)
        (1024, 518.709) 
        (2048, 868.560) 
        (4096, 1557.861)
        (8192, 2953.913)
        (16384, 5779.984)
    };    
    \addplot[blue,very thick,mark=diamond*] coordinates {     
        (128, 194.441)
        (256, 346.855) 
        (512, 592.312)
        (1024, 1100.371) 
        (2048, 2089.506) 
        (4096, 4204.929)
        (8192, 7758.365)
        (16384, 14938.887)
    }; 
    \addplot[orange,very thick,mark=*] coordinates{     
        (128, 330.123)
        (256, 583.440) 
        (512, 1046.636)
        (1024, 2149.478) 
        (2048, 4058.115) 
        (4096, 8023.846)
        (8192, 14458.539)
        (16384, 25235.819)
    }; 
    \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]